# AWS API Gateway authentication error IncompleteSignatureException using JWT with Auth0

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, aws-api-gateway, auth0

### Where I'm At

I'm currently working through setting up Auth0 delegated authentication for AWS API Gateway. I've followed the documentation and tutorials below with the exception that I have an app in place rather than their example apps:

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/aws

https://auth0.com/blog/2015/11/10/introducing-angular2-jwt-a-library-for-angular2-authentication/

https://auth0.com/docs/client-platforms/angular2

https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws-api-gateway/part-2

### What is Working

- Auth0 sign on from my Angular2 app is working correctly and I'm getting a token.
- Auth0's AuthHttp component is attaching the bearer token to the Authenticate header when I call the AWS API Gateway.

### What is Not Working

- Status 403 response from AWS API Gateway indicating a Cloudfront IncompleteSignatureException; "Authentication header missing equal-sign".

The authentication header is

```
Authentication: Bearer edJ0e...[I've truncated for brevity]
```

Could AWS be expecting a different type of authentication which uses key value pairs? How to I tell AWS API Gateway that it should be looking for a JWT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you have `AWS_IAM` authentication enabled for your API Gateway endpoint. You need to disable that if you aren't planning to use it. If you plan to use `AWS_IAM` authentication in addition to JWT then you will have to send the JWT token using a different field.

From [part 5](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws-api-gateway/part-5) of the Auth0 tutorial you linked:

> The final step is to pass the JWT to the method from the browser
>   client. The standard method is with an `Authorization` header as a
>   bearer token, and you can use this method if you turn off IAM
>   authorization and rely solely upon the OpenID token for authorization
>   (you will also need to map the Authorization header into the event
>   data passed to the AWS Lambda function). If you are using IAM, then
>   the AWS API Gateway uses the `Authorization` header to contain the
>   signature of the message, and you will break the authentication by
>   inserting the JWT into this header. You could either add a custom
>   header for the JWT, or put it into the body of the message. If you
>   choose to use a custom header, you'll also need to do some mapping for
>   the Integration Request of the POST method

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message, it sounds like you've configured your API for AWS_IAM authentication. This requires your request be signed with [AWS Signature Version 4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html).

In order to execute API Gateway functions you will need to do 1 of 3 things:

1. Get AWS credentials via IAM/STS as noted in the [auth0 example](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws-api-gateway/part-3) and use those to sign your request.
2. As noted in [Mark B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37334312/1721437), follow the instructions in [step 5](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws-api-gateway/part-5) of the tutorial from auth0 and disable AWS_IAM auth and do the validation inside your Lambda.
3. Switch to use [a custom authorizer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) to validate the JWT directly at the API Gateway layer. This would require you to take the code Auth0 provides to validate the token then build your own authorizer result.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

## Update

Both Mark B and Bob Kinney are correct. What I did (and you may have as well) is jump around in the various Auth0 links I posted at the top of this question and attempt to use their angular2-jwt library (with the AuthHttp component) to adapt the tutorial to Angular2 while following along with their 5-part example of setting up Auth0 with AWS API Gateway. The AuthHttp component will automatically put the JWT Bearer token in the "Authentication" HTTP header which is incompatible with an AWS API Gateway call secured by IAM authorization. As these gents showed me, this is explained in part 5 of the tutorial. If you only made it to part 4 and it's not working hopefully this answers your question as it did mine.

## Update 2

The Auth0 Angular2 tutorial has been updated to reflect Angular2 rc 1. https://auth0.com/blog/2015/05/14/creating-your-first-real-world-angular-2-app-from-authentication-to-calling-an-api-and-everything-in-between/